# visualization of scattered data over a sphere surface MATLAB

Tags: matlab, visualization, interpolation

I wrote a 3D finite element code and I have the values of the function C(x,y,z) (FOUND in FEM) on a bunch of scattered data (x,y,z) over a surface of the sphere. I'm trying to visualize the function using `surf` on MATLAB and I already used `griddata` to interpolate the function C over the surface of a sphere, however it does not work and I face with the following problem:

> Warning: Duplicate x-y data points detected: using average of the z
>   values

and the ultimate figure I see at the end is just a poor section of sphere.

Comment: It is hard to use `surf` to show a sphere, since it expects there to be a single Z value for each (x,y) and that's not the case for a sphere (you have a top and bottom hemisphere). Can you show some data, code you used to generate the sphere plot, and how things look - it will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example given in the [matlab documentation for plotting things on a sphere](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html), you will see (among other things) the following lines of code:

```
k = 5;
n = 2^k-1;
[x,y,z] = sphere(n);
c = hadamard(2^k);
surf(x,y,z,c);
colormap([1  1  0; 0  1  1])
axis equal
```

In this case the points on the surface are defined by their (x, y, z) coefficients, and the color is determined by the matrix `c` and the colormap `[1 1 0; 0 1 1]`. The error you describe suggests you are using `surf(x,y,z)` rather than `surf(x,y,z,c)` to create your plot. If you study the documentation referenced above you may be able to adapt the above to your situation - without a bit more information about your data it's hard to guess at a better answer.